# Bookshelfjs multiple update data not return promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bluebird, bookshelf.js

I want to update multiple row to my database. My problem is the promise not return anything. It save successfully but not return anything.

Here sample of my code:

```
doUpdate: Promise.method(function (data) {
        var self = this;
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        return Bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
            return _.each(jsonData, function (value, key) {
                var queryMatch = {
                    id: value.id,
                    id2: value.id2
                };
                return self.forge(queryMatch)
                    .fetch({transacting: t})
                    .then(function (data) {
                        return data.save({content: value.newValue});
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            });
        });
    })
```

I'm using bluebird promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to keep my code as close to yours as possible. I did manage to do what you asked, so take a look if that's something you can use.

```
doUpdate: Promise.method(function(data) {

    var Self = this;
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    return bookshelf.transaction(function(t) {
        return Promise.each(jsonData, function(value, key) {
            var queryMatch = {
                id: value.id,
                id2: value.id2
            };
            return new Self(queryMatch).save({
                content: value.newValue
            }, {
                transacting: t,
                method: 'update'
            });

        });
    });
})
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I end up use Promise.map. Maybe it same. I tried your code the save part not really work. It add row instead of update. Can you update your answer ? that save code look clean than my code. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my code, there was a small bug; however, it worked for me before, and it still works... I hope this is correct now, otherwise I fear, there might be some issues with the knex and bookshelf versions.

Comment: I tried your latest code. Now I get this error. first argument must be a string or Buffer

Comment: can you update your question and paste how you call this code? Example of the data you pass into the function?

Comment: Accept as answer as it answer my question. Thanks. Btw my mistake for the error. The real error is [Error: A model cannot be updated without a "where" clause or an idAttribute.]